# How do you increment a value after every iteration run in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am confused on how to get the value to increment every iteration? I would like it to where it increments +1 from the last value for each run. So  user 1 should be user 2 for the next test run.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKeGA.png)

I did this so far

store | 1 |i

store| javascript{storedVars.i++;}

but that didnt work. it will just type in 1 for every run.